# Create a script that fetch dependencies, install + start browser

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp, bower

I have an application on with a node server and I would like to do something like :

```
npm start
```

and node dependencies will install and bower dependencies will install, after that a browser window could open.

Can I do this without gulp/grunt? If I need gulp/grunt I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You must issue

```
npm install
```

before you call the command **npm start**, because when the scripts start to run they need the dependencies already installed.

And to start a server and open it in a browser, it's well explained here:

[How to Use npm as a Build Tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

(Look at the last example of the article)

Comment: Well I want a script that does that for me pretty much don't want to type the npm install